# node and typescript issues, won't recognize jquery

Tags: typescript

I'm having some node and typescript issues that I'm hoping someone can help me out with.

In Visual Studio 2015, I have two projects in the same solution:

Web
WebAPI

We've installed node.js on both (both have a node_modules folder) and WebAPI has some typescript files. All of a sudden, WebAPI won't compile. It complains that it can't find a whole bunch of names in the typescript files, including 'd3' and '$'. Specifically, it complains when I try to publish Web (yes, Web, I don't know why it cares what's in WebAPI but it's blocking me from publishing). If I clear the entire solution and rebuild, I get no issues; it's only when I try to publish Web. What's even more weird is that I don't get the issue when I try to publish WebAPI.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: Have you referenced the @type definition files for jquery and d3? e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> . It complains that it can't find a whole bunch of names in the typescript files, including 'd3' and '$'.

You need to include type definitions. `npm install @types/jquery -D`.

## More

Alternatively you can do simply `declare module "$";`. More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html